# Using video links within grid text field

Tags: ee3, grid, url

I have a grid called "attachments" with 2 fields.  They can enter either a File or they can enter a video url through a simple text field.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

However, when I try to create an href it gets all messed up for some reason and creates markup such as

```
<a href="a href=" https: www.youtube.com watch?etc">https: www.youtube.com watch?etc</a>"">testURL"
```

I've verified the value without the  and it spits out the url like it should, and I checked the field to make sure None was set for text formatting.

Here's my code:

```
{attachments}
  {if attachments:image_file != ""}
       <a href="{attachments:image_file}">testImg</a>
  {if:elseif attachments:video_url != ""}
       <a href="{attachments:video_url}">testURL</a>
  {/if}
{/attachments}
```

Comment: I'm using these for fancybox just so you know, that's why they are hrefs so they open in modals part of a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting in your channels​ preferences that you can toggle to automatically convert urls to links.

Find that setting and turn it off.

Comment: perfect... totally forgot about that setting, thank you!